# Subtracting from existing value using UPDATE returns negative value

Tags: mysql

I have a value in my mysql column with float as my data type. The value is 4.49.

When I run the  following command the following value is shown .. 
-0.000000228882

I am really confused as to why this is happening.

Here is the update command I am using..

```
UPDATE stores SET outstanding_balance = outstanding_balance - 4.49 , card_sales = card_sales - 4.49 , card_transactions = card_transactions - 1 WHERE store_id = 2
```

Comment: floats are not exact. That is the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Decimal
```

is the column datatype you need. Change these columns in your mysql table to this datatype. It is the most ideal for currency.